# How to inject a CSS file from an ASP.NET MVC partial view (server-side)?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a partial view (.ascx) that should include its own CSS file as it's used in multiple other views. How do I inject a stylesheet in the page server-side, i.e. without using JavaScript?

Comment: I suppose too that a good technique here would not link the stylesheet more than once, even if the partial was included multiple times.

Comment: Why can you not include a reference to your stylesheet at the beginning of your partial?

Comment: @Justin Because it's not valid XHTML.

Answer (score 2):

Dario - due to using this for partialviews, you're going to always have the problem that the  `<head>` section of the document is already in place and therefore can't be modified. If you want to remain WC3 compliant, then you'll have to put any further css into the head section via javascript. This may or may not be desirable (if you've got to cater for downsteam browsers with javascript turned off).

the main problem that you may be aluding to is the fact that you can't put `<asp:contentplaceholders>` into your partials. this is a pain (tho understandable as the masterpage ref would tie the partial too closely to a particular master page).

To this end, I've created a little helper method that does the basic grunt work to put the css file into the head section automatically.

**edit** - (as per Omu's js suggestion) this is a nice little halfway house:

```
// standard method - renders as defined in as(cp)x file
public static string Css(this HtmlHelper html, string path)
{
    return html.Css(path, false);
}
// override - to allow javascript to put css in head
public static string Css(this HtmlHelper html, string path, bool renderAsAjax)
{
    var filePath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(path);

    HttpContextBase context = html.ViewContext.HttpContext;
    // don't add the file if it's already there
    if (context.Items.Contains(filePath))
        return "";

    // otherwise, add it to the context and put on page
    // this of course only works for items going in via the current
    // request and by this method
    context.Items.Add(filePath, filePath);

    // js and css function strings
    const string jsHead = "<script  type='text/javascript'>";
    const string jsFoot = "</script>";
    const string jsFunctionStt = "$(function(){";
    const string jsFunctionEnd = "});";
    string linkText = string.Format("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"{0}\"></link>", filePath);
    string jsBody = string.Format("$('head').prepend('{0}');", linkText);

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (renderAsAjax)
    {
        // join it all up now
        sb.Append(jsHead);
        sb.AppendFormat("\r\n\t");
        sb.Append(jsFunctionStt);
        sb.AppendFormat("\r\n\t\t");
        sb.Append(jsBody);
        sb.AppendFormat("\r\n\t");
        sb.Append(jsFunctionEnd);
        sb.AppendFormat("\r\n");
        sb.Append(jsFoot);
    } 
    else
    {
        sb.Append(linkText);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

usage:

```
<%=Html.Css("~/Content/yourstyle.Css")%>
```

or:

```
<%=Html.Css("~/Content/yourstyle.Css", true)%> // or false if you want!!
```

worth a back-pocket approach if all else fails. it may also be possible to adapt the logic above to hit an actionfilter and add the css to the reponse headers etc.., rather than outputting the js string.

Comment: btw  -i found this article that adds some code to allow you to do this: http://somewebguy.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/adding-stylesheets-scripts-in-asp-net-mvc2/ then follow the links to http://gist.github.com/358458

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you cannot just put the stylesheet in the main view page?  Unless it is extremely large, it should not cause your page to load significantly slower when not being used, especially after compression.

Furthermore, if the partial view is being retrieved by ajax, you will end up re-downloading the css file multiple times (depending on the browser's caching).

Comment: I'd like my partial view to be self-contained (besides, it's rendered server-side, not loaded via AJAX).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an ASP.NET or MVC expert, but I am currently working on a project with it. Would it be possible to include something like this in the head of your master page?

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Then somehow get your CSS into the content placeholder?

```
<asp:Content ID="styleSheetHolder" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='yourstyle.css' type='text/css' />
</asp:Content>
```

It looks like you'd have to do this from the calling page, which would introduce duplication of code. I'm not sure how to get around that. Maybe it could it be done with an HTML helper.

Comment: You would have to knowingly do this outside of the partial (ie. in the page).  It'd be great if there was a solution that worked from within partials for cases that they're conditionally included.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the link tag in your partial view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourstyle.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: That renders the document invalid.

Comment: I guess the html validators are making it invalid. But I am sure the browsers are rendering properly. I don't see in specs where they tell you that it can only be inside `head` tag

Answer (score 0):

A place I worked had a site with a lot of conditional partial views, which could and would change from time to time as new things were added to the application. The best way we found was to use naming conventions - naming the partial view, stylesheet and script the same (except extension, of course).

We added one or more stylesheets, scripts and partial views to the page's view model. We then used a custom HTML helper to loop through the relevant array in each content section and insert the required content. The pain was having to manage three or more files for each component, but at least we were able to reduce the amount of maintenance in the hosting pages.

Never did resolve the problem of putting a partial view inside a partial view, though.